# PHP Equivalent of C# ticks

Tags: c#, php, date

I am currently converting a ASP.NET C# application to PHP. The service uses [DateTime Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) and I was wondering if there is an equivalent in PHP.

If not what is the best way for me to calculate a timespan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `microtime(true)`

Please note the following, straight off the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

> By default, microtime() returns a string in the form "msec sec", where
>   sec is the current time measured in the number of seconds since the
>   Unix epoch (0:00:00 January 1, 1970 GMT), and msec is the number of
>   microseconds that have elapsed since sec expressed in seconds.
>
> If get_as_float is set to TRUE, then microtime() returns a float,
>   which represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch
>   accurate to the nearest microsecond.

Comment: The value of a tick in C# is 100 nanoseconds. The microtime(true) is not a 1-to-1 as the OP asked for. Here's a good writeup on the situation (2011, but still relevant) https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/749/converting-datetime-ticks-to-a-unix-timestamp-and-back-in-php

Answer (score 2):

**[Edit: I saw later that the DateTime ticks is also quite similar to PHP DateTime->diff method, so added it; realized I missed a parameter for microtime, thanks to freedompeace.]**

I usually do it like this for benchmarking (kudo's also to freedompeace):

```
$time = microtime(true);
// do your thing
$diff = microtime(true) - $time;
```

See: http://php.net/microtime

For other dates, you can do it like this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('05-04-2010');
$date2= new DateTime('yesterday');

// returns a DateInterval object
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
```

The DateInterval object has a topology like this:

```
public integer $DateInterval->y ;
public integer $m ;
public integer $d ;
public integer $h ;
public integer $i ;
public integer $s ;
public integer $invert ;
public mixed $days ;
```

**DateTime Class** http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

**Diff method** http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

**DateInterval Object** http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do that... Seems to me like a common problem. The large "magic number" is the difference between 1970-1-1 and 1-1-1.

---

```
$mtime = microtime(false);
list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", $mtime);
$usec = (string)($usec * 10000000);
$timestamp = gmp_add(gmp_add(gmp_mul($sec, "10000000"), (string)$usec), "621355968000000000");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to recompile PHP with-gmp, this seems to work:

```
$time=time()
number_format(($time * 10000000) + 621355968000000000 , 0, '.', '');
```

Use microtime to get usec, which can then overwrite the terminating 0's.

Comment: This should be the correct answer 100%. Here's a writeup on the situation that explains ticks in PHP https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/749/converting-datetime-ticks-to-a-unix-timestamp-and-back-in-php